# Specify django-rest-framework field for serializer after request?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've got the following code:

`models.py`

```
class Interview(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, help_text="The Primary Key of the Interview")
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, help_text="The Primary Key of the Organization in the interview")
    question = name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="The Question")
```

`serializers.py`

```
class InterviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Interview
        fields = ('organization', 'question')
```

`views.py`

```
class InterviewViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows Interviews to be viewed or edited.
    """
    serializer_class = InterviewSerializer
```

Right now, the request body to create an interview requires these fields:

```
{
  "organization": "string",
  "question": "string"
}
```

I'd like the organization for the Interview to automatically be set to the current users organization (`request.user.Organization` - I've got a custom User model). How can I do this elegantly for my viewset?

Answer (score 1):

One way (probably the best) is overriding `save` / `create` / `update` methods of your ModelSerializer class. [DRF docs about it](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-save-directly)

There you can use `self.context.get("request")` to get current user. And if you still need `organization` field to be serialized, just make it `read_only=True`

Comment: That was my first thought too, but I figured there has to be an easier way using `get_serializer_context`. However, using `get_serializer_context` results in violating a `NOT NULL constraint` for me...

Comment: Not sure I understand what are going to do with `get_serializer_context`. I does nothing to saving / creating model instances. And you already have request context in your serializer, which should be enough

Comment: I'm hoping to use `get_serializer_context` to set the `organization` before passing it to the serializer, so the serializer can use it for object creation.

Comment: Anyway, you should write some code to set `organization` to your model instance before saving it, because DRF will not do this for you. There's no such magic in it